# Laravel DB::transaction exception PDO There is no active transaction

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, transactions, eloquent

i have the following code:

```
$new_models = DB::transaction(function () use ($supplier, $address, $addressDetail) {            
        $new_supplier = $this->setNewSupplier($supplier);
        $new_address = $this->setNewAddress($address);           
        $new_addressDetail = $this->setNewAddressDetail($addressDetail,$new_address->id);           
        $this->syncSupplierAddress($new_supplier->id,$new_address->id);
        $this->updateControlAp($new_supplier->supplier_id);   
        return [$new_supplier, $new_address, $new_addressDetail];
    });
```

The set methods are basically creating the models object with save() at the end;
Now this works perfectly fine if 2nd...nth fails BUT NOT if the first one fails.
If `$this->setNewSupplier($supplier);`
fails than i get

```
"PDOException in Connection.php line 541:
There is no active transaction"
```

Am i doing something wrong here ? Also if i comment `$this->rollBack();` from the catch in vendor Connection.php it actually gives me the SQL error. Important part here is that this isn't working only if first save() fails

PS. I am using PostgreSQL not MySQL but i don't think its related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to make transactions in Laravel, another one could be this:

```
...
$new_models = [];
try {
  DB::beginTransaction();

  $new_supplier = $this->setNewSupplier($supplier);
  $new_address = $this->setNewAddress($address);           
  $new_addressDetail = $this->setNewAddressDetail($addressDetail,$new_address->id);           
  $this->syncSupplierAddress($new_supplier->id,$new_address->id);
  $this->updateControlAp($new_supplier->supplier_id);   
  $new_models = [$new_supplier, $new_address, $new_addressDetail];

  DB::commit();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
   DB::rollback();
   // Handle Error
}
...
```

Comment: I tried your code and it still behaves the same way. In catch if i use 
`catch(\Exception $e) {
//DB::rollback();
            throw $e;
        }` i get the error but if i uncomment rollback still PDO: There is no active transaction if first save() fails. I actually think the save() method does the rollback. Gonna test your code without rollback in catch if actually every save() called does rollback on fail.